# Jasmine tests will not complete (hang) while using Appium and WebDriverIO

Tags: typescript, automation, jasmine, appium, webdriver-io

I cloned the [WebDriverIO Boilerplate](https://github.com/amiya-pattnaik/webdriverIO-with-jasmineBDD) repository, and added the capabilities and my APK.

The framework correctly launches the APK on the emulator, but the jasmine wont complete the test case for up to 5 minutes.

The test case is as simple as this:

```
describe('Android App Test', () => {
    it('should install and launch the app', async () => {
        console.log("Getting Started")
        await const logo = await $('~logo')
        await logo.waitForDisplayed({ timeout: 25000 });
        await expect( logo.isDisplayed()).toBe(true)

        console.log("Code made it here......")
        await driver.closeApp()
    }); 
  });
```

The console logs are printing, and the application is correctly closing.
However, the test is hanging for 4 minutes before it finishes.

I'm not sure why, is it something on appium waiting to complete, a async function hanging?

I made the test as simple as `console.log("hello world")` (Appium still launches)

I'm using these versions:

- node v19.9.0
- appium-webdriver: 1.0.2
- webdriverio: 8.1.3
- ts-node: 10.9.1
- @wdio/jasmine-framework: 8.1.3

Comment: what is the nodejs and webdriverio versions you are using?

Comment: @Raju 
appium-webdriver: 1.0.2
webdriverio: 8.1.3
ts-node: 10.9.1
node v19.9.0

And thank you, I updated my question with this.

Comment: the appium version does not seem right. Do you have a sample repo or something on github?

Answer (score 0):

Running into to same issue. my session on saucelabs completes and jasmine test is still waiting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).